# Rudin 2.17 definition: balls are convex

Tags: real-analysis

While I was going through the definition 2.17 in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, I could not comprehend the proof for "balls are convex".

> if x $\in R^k$ and r > 0, the *open(or closed) ball* B with center at x and radius r is defined to be the set of all y $\in R^k$ such that |y-x|$\lt$r (or |y-x|$\le$ r).
>
> We call a set E $\subset$ $R^k$ *convex* if $$ \lambda x + (1- \lambda)y \in E $$ whenever x $\in $ E, y $\in $ E and 0<$\lambda$<1.
>
> For example, *balls are convex*. For if |y-x|$\lt$r, |z-x|$\lt$r, and 0<$\lambda$<1, we have $$|\lambda y + (1-\lambda)z -x| = |\lambda (y-x) + (1-\lambda)(z-x)|$$ $$\le \lambda |y-x| + (1-\lambda)|z-x| \lt \lambda r + (1-\lambda)r = r$$

Here I have the following questions. Does |$\lambda$y + (1 - $\lambda$)z - x| $\lt$ r mean |$\lambda$y + (1 - $\lambda$)z - x|$\in$ E in the definition? Then since |y-x|$\lt$r and |z-x|$\lt$r, hence |y-x|$\in$E, |z-x|$\in$E, why can't we directly use $\lambda$|y-x| + (1-$\lambda$)|z-x| in the first place, instead of using |$\lambda$y + (1 - $\lambda$)z - x|?

Comment: $|λy + (1 - λ)z - x| < r$ mean $λy + (1 - λ)z \in E$

Comment: It just means that $\lambda y +(1-\lambda)z \in E = B(x,r)$.

Comment: @copper.hat 3sec. between comments(!).

Comment: I am 3 light seconds away

Comment: @zkutch That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you!